# Don't write values to excel sheet that are nan

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to write only the rows who's value of a certain column is not equal to nan. An easy solution would be to drop all rows with the data equal to nan, however I am trying to preserve all of the data in the dataframe.

My thinking was to see if the value at the current location of a specific column was not equal to nan. If so then write that value out to the excel file.

```
if (df99.loc[df99['name'] != 'np.nan']):
    df99['name'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet1', startrow = 12, 
    startcol = 6, index=False, header=False )
```

If I have a dataframe with entries at indices 10, 20, and 30 I want it to still be written at the same indices in the excel sheet (11, 21, 31). I am trying to maintain their positions.

Comment: try with `notnull()` since `np.nan!=np.nan` is `True` guess `df99.loc[df99['name'].notnull(),'A TYP'].to_excel(writer,....)`

Comment: @anky_91 this doesn't seem to have the desired effect. It writes all of the data one after another at the very beginning. If the df has an entry at index 75 I want it to be written to the excel sheet at row 76 (since excel index starts at 1 not 0).

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of the original dataframe where you drop the Nans and then write that to Excel. That should do the work, if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't preserve the location that it should be written to. All of the data will just be written one after another at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just do this.

```
# convert all nulls, NAN, etc., to 0
# don't want to deal with NANs...
df = df.fillna(0)
df


# count nulls in each field; 
# we're getting 0 so our results look good
df.isnull().sum()
```